# Javascript Date Format Conversion for comparison

Tags: javascript, regex

My objective to get the date in day month year format from a textbox and convert it to mm/dd/yyyy format so that i can compare dates

```
var userDate = document.getElementById("dateOfJourney").value; //eg 21/05/2013
var formattedUserDate = new Date( userDate.replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));
alert(formattedUserDate);
```

i'm trying to escape 'forward slash' but i'm getting invalid date
output eg. 05/21/2013

Comment: Read this first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: For sorting, you should have the year first, not last.

Answer (score 1):

You could have done like.

```
var userDate = "21/5/2013".split("/");
var newDate = userDate[1]+"/"+userDate[0]+"/"+userDate[2];
var formattedUserDate = new Date(newDate);
alert(formattedUserDate);
```

instead of using the regex. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtjgk/) is a working sample.